# How to get SAML based sign-on setting via MS Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, single-sign-on

I'm currently learning about Azure, and using MS Graph API. I am having a problem when using an application that has SAML based sign-on installed. I want to get the following configuration through the Graph API for the application side to process, but I can't find any MS Graph API support to get the information I need.
I hope everyone can help, Thanks.
[c#]

SAML based sign-on

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

For Configuring SAML-based single sign-on for your application using the Microsoft Graph API please check out this reference document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/application-saml-sso-configure-api

Hope this helps.